# ExtJS - Save the state of ExtJS component in database

Tags: extjs

Do you have any Idea how to save the state (width, collapsible, ...) of a ExtJS component in database, not in cookies.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?24970-Buffering-Http-State-Provider

Comment: http://numberformat.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/extjs-restful-state-provider/

Comment: What's the ExtJs version? 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: I'm using ExtJS 4.1.3

Comment: This is a bit old question, but recently I found this nice working code: https://github.com/hlsolutions/extjs-components/tree/master/src/HttpStateProvider/hlx/base/state Maybe this will solve Your problem

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is implement a [provider](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.state.Provider) that is used by the [stateful](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.state.Stateful) component you are using.

In your `Ext.state.Provider`, you implement `get` and `set` to use your database, probably with AJAX, maybe even using Ext's [RESTful](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest) stores

Then you tell your application to use your custom provider by calling

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(foo.providers.AjaxProvider);
```

For an example customization, see http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.state.CookieProvider

Comment: Exactly, we wrote our on DBProvider extending the Ext.state.Provider as Juan stated above. It's important that you tell the state manager which provider to use before your app has loaded.